# Is ж softened when followed by i? E.g. are the two ж's in жінка жне different?

Tags: фонетика, non-native-speaker

The title says it all really.  A friend of mine who's also learning Ukrainian says she hears жінка as starting with a softened sound; I always assumed it was a hard sound but now I'm having doubts. Which is it?

If anyone knows Polish, my question is whether it's a ż or a ź. Or which one of ʒ, ʐ, or possibly ʑ it is in [the IPA chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_pulmonic_consonant_chart_with_audio).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case, I write about only standard orthoepy here, because in other case itʼd be a pretty big article, because *i* [came](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86_(%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F)#%D0%97%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA_%D1%96)<sup>1</sup> from some different sounds, mostly *и* (migrated), *ѣ* and *o*.

> Is *ж* softened when followed by *i*?

Yes, but itʼs **half-softened**<sup>2</sup> which means barely softened. So Polish language canʼt help here. The situation is almost the same with IPA because:

> <sup>[«*Ukrainian. Illustrations of the IPA*» by *Bernd Pompino-Marschall*,
> *Elena Steriopolo*, *Marzena Zygis*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309771383_Ukrainian_Illustrations_of_the_IPA)</sup>
>
> Adhering to the IPA conventions, here the [superscript [ʲ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(phonetics)) is used for both palatalized and semi-palatalized consonants.

By the way, *ж* is [ʒ].

There are no standard of Ukrainian transcription but the language usually differentiates semi- and hard-palatalization by two types of apostrophes or something like this. I use *бідність* where two different type of consonants before *i*, and a *softening sign*:

- [б’і́д`н`іс`т`] — [Горох](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C);
- [б’і́д´н´іс´т´] — [Погрібний](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0001490), where at the beginning of the book you can also read most rules of orthoepy;
- [б"і́д'н'іс'т'] — you may also notice [something like this](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8#%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2).

> E.g. are the two *ж*'s in *жінка*, *жне* different?

Therefore we know **thatʼre**: [ж"інка] and [жне].

---

But, I guess, it isnʼt enough because we need some **rules** for this:

- *д*, *т*, *з*, *с*, *дз*, *ц*, *л*, *н* before *i* are always hard-softened;
- *й* always stays the same because the sound is soft itself;
- the rest are semi-softened; *р* is debatable, but usually itʼs here;

Thereʼs also [an assimilation by palatalization](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%96_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96#%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%BC%27%D1%8F%D0%BA%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8E%5B2%5D), where *usually* (which means *not always*) are:

- a hard-soft group + hard-soft = hard-soft + hard-soft: *дня* → [д'н'а]
- a hard-soft group + semi-soft = hard-soft + semi-soft: *світ* → [с'в"іт] (not necessary).

---

<sup>Notes</sup>

1. If youʼre interested in linguistic [history] then you may read about [icavism](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC).
2. In Ukrainian itʼs usually called *напівмʼякий* or *напівпомʼякшений*, sometimes *частково мʼякий*. Maybe thereʼre other variations. And for English itʼs usually *semi-* or *half-* + *-palatalized* or *-softened*.